# How can I load post/page via ajax?

Tags: wordpress

I know this has been done before, but I can't find any tutorial or article on the subject.

I have a normal menu in a widget, each menu item pointing to a different post/page. I also have an empty div where the post should be loaded.

```
<div id="ajax_content"></div>
```

I just want to be able to load the post in that div whenever a menu item is clicked.

How can I do that?

Any tutorial or article that explains how this is done?

Does a plugin exist that accomplishes this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [AJAX Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pO-FYVZv94) by [Pippin Williamson](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSlxGIoycwNUEApJfUAlKFg) on WP Back end AJAX helped me a lot on how AJAX works in WP.

He shows how to show top 5 posts via AJAX in the WP Backend by clicking a button. I'm sure you can manipulate the code and make it help you in your case.

The difference is just that you need to load the scripts on the front end by using [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) instead of [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Hope this helps ..